# Adding a new column in which filling the column ,for first 6 rows fill it with 1 to 6 number same to next 6 rows with python

Tags: python, preprocessor

I am trying to add a new column in which every 6 rows in the dataframe is filled with  1 to 6 numbers.
Repeating it for all the rows in the dataframe. The illustration below shows how the output should look like

**input**

```
    ID
0   20
1   20
2   20
3   20
4   20
5   20
6   34
7   34
8   34
9   34
10  34
11  34
12  67
13  67
14  67
15  67
16  67
17  67
```

****output****

```
    ID  6_months
0   20         1
1   20         2
2   20         3
3   20         4
4   20         5
5   20         6
6   34         1
7   34         2
8   34         3
9   34         4
10  34         5
11  34         6
12  67         1
13  67         2
14  67         3
15  67         4
16  67         5
17  67         6
```

Comment: Please share where is data is CSV, panda data frame, or simple list.

Comment: panda data frame